# Full Calendar eventElement.draggable is not a function When using the `editable: true` option

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I've currently run into an issue using the Full Calendar `editable: true`, or any editable option. Im currently running jquery 3.3.1 and it seems whenever I hover over the event object I made it will give me the `eventElement.draggable is not a function` error.

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar']),
], function($, _, Backbone){
```

heres my define above

```
    $(function(){
            $('#ticketCal', this.el).fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                    ignoreTimezone: false
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                selectable: true,
                eventStartEditable: true,
                events: [
                    {
                      title  : 'event1',
                      start  : '2019-02-06',
                      end    : '2019-02-09'
                    },
                    {
                      title  : 'event2',
                      start  : '2019-02-05',
                      end    : '2019-02-06'
                    },
                    {
                        title  : 'event3',
                        start  : '2019-02-09T12:30:00',
                        allDay : false
                      }
                  ],
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    console.log('Clicked on: ' + date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
                  }, 
                  eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {
                      console.log("event click",event)
                   }
            });
        });
```

above is the code I am using. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong to cause this error? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `draggable` is a jQuery-UI method, so you will need to add a reference to `jQuery-UI`.

Here is a link to [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Comment: Wow its always the simplest of things :D I wasnt aware of jquery-ui till now! Thank you good sir.